# jquery datatables for image thumbnail gallery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm familiar with using jquery.datatables() plugin for displaying rows/columns of data from mySQL. The built-in options for server side data sources, searching, pagination, ect... are great.

But, I'd like to extend the plugin to display a grid of image thumbnails. Users could use a drop down box to filter the images, (just a datatables sSearch[]), pagination, and all the other standard datatables options.

Anyone know how i'd format the table?
It would basically be columns of rows?

thanks.

Comment: This is not a dataTables-specific issue. If you look for a "secret" feature you'll get disappointed. Solution : A thumbnail gallery would just be a table styled into a grid layout, containing columns of `<img src=`, in dataTables, write a customfilter that can sort the images based on their name (or other metadata) in orher words, straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

There was a discussion on this topic on the datatables forum, https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/6711/grid-mode - at the time the official response was that it couldn't be done. However, one of the forum members did come up with a solution that looks quite good and is demonstrated here: http://www.masterlecture.com/mod/tutorrank/